# Size of UIViewController not resized on push

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UINavigationController` that has a search bar in its titleView. It looks like this:

[image: Search bar in navigation bar]

After I push a view on top of the stack from that page, the search bar is hidden and so the navigation bar size decreases. This should resize the page that it pushes but instead it just leaves a black gap like this:

[image: Black gap in navigation bar on push]

How can I fix this?

**EDIT**
If I include `self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true` then it no longer has that black bar... However, I ideally do not want to be setting this as it messes up the view when accessed in other places.

Comment: Have you tried Xcode's view debugging tool to see what is influencing the view size and location?

Comment: @PhillipMills No... but I'm not sure how to use that?

Comment: @PhillipMills Ok I pressed the view debugging thing, the black gap is the navigation controller's bg colour. The nav bar has shrunk, and the view has kept the same size as it's previous one.

Comment: The _UILayoutGuide seems to be in the wrong place